# Forward a port to all users in Mikrotik RouterOS

Tags: router, vpn, port-forwarding, nat, mikrotik-routeros

#### In short:

I want to know how to forward certain ports on Mikrotik's RouterOS. I looked up online and found several videos/tutorials but for whatever reason, I cannot do it. Please read below for more info

#### Details:

I use a ping reduction service for online gaming. The services is a VPN at its core which uses a very fast port to send and receive data in order to reduce the overall ping and increase online gaming quality.

The company that sells this VPN (let's call them A) buys the bandwidth from another company (let's call these ones B). They B company gives the A company a Mikrotik RouterOS panel and A uses it to give us the VPN service.

Now, as you may know, the online gaming requires forwarding certain ports to be forwarded in order to achieve an Open NAT type. I contacted the A company and told them about this. They contacted B and they said that the ports are now opened for them. The A company tried to forward the ports and told me that they've done it but I still get the Strict/Moderate NAT on my games.

If I connect directly, I get the Open NAT. So I think that my configuration is correct. I just connect to VPN and try again but it goes to Strict/Moderate.

Also, I tried http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ but on both direct and VPN connections it says that the port is closed!! (even though I get the Open NAT). I have set my Ethernet connection to be a static IP and in my network and configed my modem for the ports. Here's what it looks like:

[image: My config]

There could be a problem on B, A or my side and I'm not sure how to check it on either of them. Can company A check the ports on RouterOS to see if they're forwarded? Is there a way for me to check them? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You do know, that there is no such thing as a "very fast port"?

Comment: @EugenRieck I'd rather don't get into the details of how it works. Just trust me on the fact that it works and I'm more interested in finding the solution for the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the NAT, DMZ are best solution. In the console

```
ip firewall
```

Add action=src-nat chain=srcnat comment=dmz-src disabled=yes src-address=192.168.1.0 to-addresses=201.x.x.x

```
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment=dmz-dst disabled=no dst-address=201.x.x.x  to-addresses=192.168.1.0


add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment=masquerade-local out-interface=WAN
```

Where dst-address its your public IP and to-address are your local router/gaming pc.